# negative value of Checksum: Flyway

Tags: sql, spring-boot, flyway

What does the negative value of Checksum in **flyway_schema_history** table indicate? Does it mean that updating the database/sql query execution wasn't successful? Conversely, does positive value of checksum indicate a successful flyway migration?